# Работа с датами SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Привет всем.Никто не подскажет,как взять временную метку начала текущей недели ? (T-SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=998

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и понятный способ такой:

```
DECLARE @dt char(8);
SET @dt = convert(char(8),getdate(),112)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @dt), @dt)
```

Но есть другой, в котором куча вычитаний частей даты:

```
SELECT dateadd(ms, -datepart(ms,getdate()),dateadd(s, -datepart(s,getdate()), dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi,getdate()),dateadd(hh, -datepart(hh,getdate()),DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), getdate())))))
```

Что вам больше приглянется - выбирайте.